# Reference request: unusual expansion of product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, quantum-groups, q-analogs

There is a well-known formula for the product of the binomial coefficients:
$$\binom{n}{a}\binom{n}{b}=\sum_{i=0}^{min(a,b)}\binom{a+b-i}{i,a-i,b-i}\binom{n}{a+b-i}$$

I'm interested in a different formula for the expansion of the product, where the RHS only contains binomial coefficients of the form $\binom{n+i}{a+b}$:
$$\binom{n}{a}\binom{n}{b}=\sum_{i=0}^{a+b}\binom{a}{i}\binom{b}{i}\binom{n+i}{a+b}$$

More generally,
$$\binom{n+c}{a}\binom{n+d}{b}=\sum_{i=0}^{a+b}\binom{a-c+d}{i-c}\binom{b-d+c}{i-d}\binom{n+i}{a+b}$$

This holds whenever $0\le c \le a$ and $0 \le d \le b$, and it comes from [this MO answer regarding a quantized version of the formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446705/what-is-the-ring-structure-on-lusztigs-integral-form-of-quantum-mathfraksl).

I'm almost certain that I'm not the first to find this formula, but identities involving binomial coefficients are hard to sort through. I was wondering if someone remembers having seen this before and could point me to a reference.

Comment: I think there are some good pointers here: [Sum of binomial coefficients involving ,,,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2088564/499816)

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein thank you! These all seem relevant and include special cases of the formula I stated. However, I could not find the most general statement anywhere. Maybe I missed it in Gould's book - a lot of specializations to try in similar looking formulas - but I was unable to retrieve it.

Comment: I think if we start with a formula in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2245619/499816), substitute $(r,s,m,n,k):=(n+d,n+c,a,b,i-d)$, then we would obtain precisely the "more generally" identity in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove the identity while we wait for a reference to appear.
We seek with $0\le c\le a$ and $0\le d\le b$

$${n+c\choose a} {n+d\choose b}
= \sum_{q=0}^{a+b} {a-c+d\choose q-c} {b-d+c\choose q-d}
{n+q\choose a+b}.$$

We get for the RHS

$$[z^{a+b}] \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q {a-c+d\choose a+d-q} {b-d+c\choose b+c-q}
{n+q\choose a+b}
\\ = [z^{a+b}] \frac{1}{1-z} 
[w^{a+d}] (1+w)^{a-c+d} [v^{b+c}] (1+v)^{b-d+c}
\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q w^q v^q
{n+q\choose a+b}
\\ = [z^{a+b}] \frac{1}{1-z} 
[w^{a+d}] (1+w)^{a-c+d} [v^{b+c}] (1+v)^{b-d+c}
[u^{a+b}] (1+u)^n
\\ \times \sum_{q\ge 0} z^q w^q v^q (1+u)^q
\\ = [z^{a+b}] \frac{1}{1-z} 
[w^{a+d}] (1+w)^{a-c+d} [v^{b+c}] (1+v)^{b-d+c}
[u^{a+b}] (1+u)^n
\frac{1}{1-zwv(1+u)}
\\ = - [z^{a+b+1}] \frac{1}{1-z} 
[w^{a+d+1}] (1+w)^{a-c+d} [v^{b+c}] (1+v)^{b-d+c}
\\ \times [u^{a+b}] (1+u)^{n-1}
\frac{1}{v-1/z/w/(1+u)}.$$

The contribution from $v$ is

$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{b+c+1}} (1+v)^{b-d+c}
\frac{1}{v-1/z/w/(1+u)}.$$

Here we see that the residue at infinity is zero, so we may use minus
the residue at $v=1/z/w/(1+u)$ (residues sum to zero):

$$- (1+u)^{b+c+1} z^{b+c+1} w^{b+c+1} 
\frac{(zw(1+u)+1)^{b-d+c}}{z^{b-d+c} w^{b-d+c} (1+u)^{b-d+c}}
\\ = - (1+u)^{d+1} z^{d+1} w^{d+1} 
(zw(1+u)+1)^{b-d+c}.$$

Substitute into the remaining extractors,

$$[z^{a+b-d}] \frac{1}{1-z} 
[w^a] (1+w)^{a-c+d} [u^{a+b}] (1+u)^{n+d}
(zw(1+u)+1)^{b-d+c}.$$

The contribution from $z$ is

$$\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^{a+b-d+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
(zw(1+u)+1)^{b-d+c}.$$

Using  the the  inequalities as  stated in  the preliminaries  we find
again that the residue  at infinity is zero, and we  may use minus the
residue  at   $z=1.$  We  also   note  that   there  is  no   pole  at
$z=-1/w/(1+u).$ Collecting the remaining two extractors, we get

$$[w^a] (1+w)^{a-c+d} [u^{a+b}] (1+u)^{n+d}
(w(1+u)+1)^{b-d+c}
\\ = [w^a] (1+w)^{a-c+d} [u^{a+b}] (1+u)^{n+d}
(1+w+uw)^{b-d+c}
\\ = [w^a] (1+w)^{a-c+d} [u^{a+b}] (1+u)^{n+d}
\sum_{q=0}^{b-d+c} {b-d+c\choose q} 
(1+w)^{b-d+c-q} u^q w^q
\\ = [u^{a+b}] (1+u)^{n+d}
\sum_{q=0}^{b-d+c} {b-d+c\choose q} 
{a+b-q\choose a-q} u^q
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{b-d+c} {b-d+c\choose q} 
{a+b-q\choose a-q} {n+d\choose a+b-q}.$$

Here  we  have  by  construction   that  the  rightmost  two  binomial
coefficients are zero when the  lower index goes negative.  This means
that we can replace the upper range by $a$. If $a\lt b-d+c$ we get for
$q\gt a$ that the second binomial coefficient is zero. If $b-d+c\lt a$
we  get  for $q\gt  b-d+c$  that  the  first binomial  coefficient  is
zero. We thus have

$$\sum_{q=0}^a {b-d+c\choose q} 
{a+b-q\choose a-q} {n+d\choose a+b-q}.$$

Now observe that

$${a+b-q\choose a-q} {n+d\choose a+b-q}
= \frac{(n+d)!}{(a-q)!\times b! \times (n+d+q-a-b)!}
\\ = {n+d\choose b} {n+d-b\choose a-q}.$$

We thus obtain

$${n+d\choose b} \sum_{q=0}^a 
{b-d+c\choose q} {n+d-b\choose a-q}.$$

Here we may use Vandermonde which yields

$${n+d\choose b} {n+c\choose a}.$$

This is the  claim. It is interesting  to try this sum  with the major
CAS.

Comment: I didn't know of this technique to prove these kinds of identities, but it looks very powerful! Fantastic proof, thanks!

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Great derivation! To start with this very first step is already instructive. (+1)

Comment: @epi163sqrt Thanks! Would you be interested in writing the commentary for this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703564/)?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: You're welcome. I'm a bit busy at the moment, but I will soon give it a try. Kind regards,

Comment: @epi163sqrt The proof has been extended to include a missing positivity argument.