# Prove combination of polynomials must be odd polynomials with positive coefficients.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Let $m,n\geq0$ are integers, show that
$$p_{m,n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{2x+2k}{2k+1} \binom{n+m-k-x-\frac{1}{2}}{m-k}$$
must be an odd polynomial(all coefficients of even power of $x$ is $0$) with positive coefficients.

Where the binomial coefficients is used as polynomials, which is defined by
$$
\binom{x}{n}=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots(x-n+1)}{n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots 2 \cdot 1}
$$

Using the rising factorials, we can express $p_{m,n}(x)$ in the following way
$$
p_{m,n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{(2x)^{(2k+1)}}{(2k+1)!} \frac{(\frac12+n-x)^{(m-k)}}{(m-k)!},
$$
where the rising factorial is defined as follows
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{(n)}& =\overbrace{x(x+1)(x+2) \cdots(x+n-1)}^{n \text { factors }}  =\prod_{k=1}^n(x+k-1)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k) ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where the value of $x^{(n)}$ is taken to be 1 (an empty product) when $n = 0$.

I can only prove the special case of $n=0$ via complicated analytic bypass, and I failed to prove the general $n\geq1$. I wonder if there is a nature combinatorial proof...

Update: Is it possilble to calculate the asymptotic of $P_{m,n}(x)$ for $n$ goes to infinity?  I can only get the asymptotic for special $x=-1/2$, is there some way to derive the asymptotics for general $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first try to simplify the sum

$$P_{m,n}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^m {2x+2k\choose 2k+1}
{n+m-k-x-1/2\choose m-k}.$$

We get

$$- [z^m] (1+z)^{n+m-x-1/2}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {-2x\choose 2k+1} z^k (1+z)^{-k}.$$

Here we have extended to infinity due to the coefficient extractor.
Next,

$$- [z^m] (1+z)^{n+m-x-1/2}
\sum_{k\ge 0} z^k (1+z)^{-k}
[w^{2k+1}] (1+w)^{-2x}
\\ = - [z^{2m}] (1+z^2)^{n+m-x-1/2}
\sum_{k\ge 0} z^{2k} (1+z^2)^{-k}
[w^{2k+1}] (1+w)^{-2x}
\\ = - [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{n+m-x-1/2} \sqrt{1+z^2}
\sum_{k\ge 0} z^{2k+1} (1+z^2)^{-k-1/2}
[w^{2k+1}] (1+w)^{-2x}
\\ = - [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{n+m-x}
\frac{1}{2} ((1+z/\sqrt{1+z^2})^{-2x}
-(1-z/\sqrt{1+z^2})^{-2x})
\\ = - [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{n+m}
\frac{1}{2} ((z+\sqrt{1+z^2})^{-2x}
-(-z+\sqrt{1+z^2})^{-2x}).$$

We know from the initial representation that this is a polynomial in
$x.$ Extract the coefficient on $[x^q]$

$$[x^q] \exp(-2x \log(\pm z+\sqrt{1+z^2}))
= \frac{(-1)^q 2^q}{q!} \log^q(\pm z+\sqrt{1+z^2}).$$

The  logarithms  are  both  valid  formal  power  series  because  the
arguments are formal power series that start with constant coefficient
equal to one. Note however that

$$\log(-z+\sqrt{1+z^2}) = - \log\frac{1}{-z+\sqrt{1+z^2}}
\\ = -\log\frac{z+\sqrt{1+z^2}}{1+z^2-z^2}
= -\log(z+\sqrt{1+z^2}).$$

This yields

$$[x^q] P_{m,n}(x)
= - [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{n+m}
\frac{(-1)^q 2^q}{q!} 
\frac{1}{2} \log^q(z+\sqrt{1+z^2}) (1-(-1)^q).$$

This is  zero when  $q$ is even  (inspect last term)  and we  have the
claim. We get for $q$ odd the coefficient

$$\frac{2^q}{q!} [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{n+m}
\log^q(z+\sqrt{1+z^2}).$$

The powered logarithm starts at $z^q$ so we get zero when $q\gt 2m+1.$
To see positivity note that an alternate representation is

$$(-1)^{m+1} [z^m] (1+z)^{x-1/2-n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {-2x\choose 2k+1} (-1)^k z^k
\\ = (-1)^{m+1} [z^m] (1+z)^{x-1/2-n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k z^k [w^{2k+1}] (1+w)^{-2x}
\\ = (-1)^{m+1} [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{x-1/2-n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k z^{2k+1} [w^{2k+1}] (1+w)^{-2x}
\\ = i (-1)^m [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{x-1/2-n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} i^{2k+1}  z^{2k+1} [w^{2k+1}] (1+w)^{-2x}
\\ = \frac{i}{2} (-1)^m [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{x-1/2-n}
((1+iz)^{-2x}-(1-iz)^{-2x})
\\ = \frac{i}{2} (-1)^m [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{-1/2-n}
\left[ \left( \frac{1-iz}{1+iz} \right)^x
- \left( \frac{1+iz}{1-iz} \right)^x \right].$$

Extract the coefficient on $[x^q]$ to get

$$\frac{i}{2q!} (-1)^m [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{-1/2-n}
\left[ \log^q \frac{1-iz}{1+iz}
- \log^q \frac{1+iz}{1-iz} \right]
\\ = \frac{i}{2q!} (-1)^m [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{-1/2-n}
\log^q \frac{1-iz}{1+iz} (1-(-1)^q).$$

Zero again for $q$ even, and for $q$ odd,

$$\frac{i}{q!} (-1)^m [z^{2m+1}] (1+z^2)^{-1/2-n}
\log^q \frac{1-iz}{1+iz}
\\ = \frac{1}{q!} [z^{2m+1}] (1-z^2)^{-1/2-n}
\log^q \frac{1+z}{1-z}.$$

The two terms in the product both have series in positive terms only.
To see this, note that the first one is

$$\sum_{p\ge 0} {-1/2-n\choose p} (-1)^p z^{2p}
= \sum_{p\ge 0} {p+n-1/2\choose p} z^{2p}.$$

The coefficients are positive because $(p+n-1/2)^{\underline{p}}$ is.
Note also that

$$\log\frac{1+z}{1-z}
= \log\left(1+\frac{2z}{1-z}\right)
= \sum_{p\ge 1} (-1)^{p-1} \frac{2^p z^p}{p (1-z)^p}.$$

This means the coefficient on $[z^r]$ is

$$\sum_{p=1}^r (-1)^{p-1} 2^p [z^{r-p}] \frac{1}{p (1-z)^p}
= \sum_{p=1}^r (-1)^{p-1} 2^p {r-1\choose p-1} \frac{1}{p}
\\ = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{p=1}^r (-1)^{p-1} 2^p {r\choose p}
= - \frac{1}{r} ((1-2)^r-1) =  - \frac{1}{r} ((-1)^r-1).$$

This is zero  when $r$ is even  and $\frac{2}{r}$ when $r$  is odd. We
have established  the desired  positivity of  the coefficients,  as we
have the product of a series  with positive coefficients times a power
of a series that also has positive coefficients.

Comment: @lomarkly The proof was not quite complete, it still needed the positivity part. This is now included.

Comment: Thank you for your great patient! It's very detailed!

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Remarkable derivation - a pleasure to go through it in detail. (+1)

Comment: Is it possilble to calculate the asymptotic of $P_{m,n}(x)$ for $n$ goes to infinity?  I can only get the asymptotic for special $x=-1/2$, is there some way to derive the asymptotics for general $x$?

Comment: The leading coefficient on $[x^q]$ where $q=2m+1$ is $2^q/q!.$